# Terminology for parties in authentication protocols

Tags: authentication, terminology

Is there a common terminology to designate parties in authentication protocols?

For example, we typically use ***prover*** and ***verifier*** to designate parties with zero-knowledge proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems so: **User** and **Principal**/**Party**

In *Protocols For Authentication And Key Establishment*, published this year and written by
Colin Boyd, Anish Mathuria, and Douglas Stebila, it says this in Section 1.2.2:

> In the following,
>   we use the term **user** to mean an entity who will use the session key for subsequent
>   communication. We also use the term **principal or party** to mean an entity who will
>   engage in the protocol. For example, in a protocol which uses a key server (often
>   called an authentication server) there are **users** who will obtain the session key while
>   the server is a **principal** but not a user.

These terms occur throughout the the international standard ISO/IEC documentation. Just one example is ISO/IEC 11770-2 Server-Based Protocols, in the section about key establishment mechanisms.